# git-cvsimport cannot import tag containing an asterisk in it's name (*)

Tags: git, cvs

I'm trying to import `cvs` repository to `git` using `git cvsimport`. It says: `Cannot create tag aspect-10*2-root: Illegal seek`. I've looked through `git cvsimport` man and didn't find a possibility to replace an arbitrary symbol in a tag/branch name with another symbol, nor I found a way to omit certain tags. When `git cvsimport` encounters tag contains an asterisk it exits with an error and no `git` repo is created. Please advise how to solve this problem.

Comment: Looking at it from another angle, would it be feasible to rename the tag in CVS to remove the asterisk?